# grid view layout settings in android

Tags: android, gridview

I have created grid view for my wallpaper application but I am facing a problem with my layout. My grid view layout changes with different devices. I want the same view for all devices. Help me out.

**This is my xml file.**

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnWidth="30dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
android:numColumns="2"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/gridview"
```

And **this is Imageadapter file in which I have set my grid view.**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageView imgGrid;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            imgGrid = new ImageView(current);
            imgGrid.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(300,200));
            imgGrid.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);

            imgGrid.getScaleType();
            imgGrid.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        }
        else
        {
            imgGrid = (ImageView)convertView;
        }

        imgGrid.setImageResource(images[position]);

        return imgGrid;
    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this line

```
imgGrid.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(300,200));
```

with

```
imgGrid.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
```

feel change to pass `layout params` parameter. But don't give large values it won't look good on other devices.

Comment: Yes I got you but still the same problem. After I changed it, my grid view looks differrent in different devices.

Comment: what do you mean by different on different device?? Sorry, I didn't understand you properly.

Comment: In my Xperia U, images look larger than HTC one or Xperia Z. I want the same view for all devices. Like "Auto resize images"

Comment: For that you have to use different image resolution. Put the different resolution images in the `res` folder. I think you know look at here [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)